# JAVA - Como imprimir los atributos que asigne en mis objetos?

Tags: java

Estoy usando Iterator con su respectiva libreria, compila, pero me arroja este resultado:

> COSTOS@940a5a93 COSTOS@940a5a93

Este es mi codigo:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public final class ListaConcepto {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        List<COSTOS> Lista = new ArrayList<COSTOS>();

        COSTOS obj1 = new COSTOS(1781, 359.13, "BISAG.SUP.PUER.TRA.I", "67550T9AT00ZZ");
        COSTOS obj2 = new COSTOS(1781, 359.13, "BISAG.SUP.PUER.TRA.I", "67550T9AT00ZZ");

        Lista.add(obj1);
        Lista.add(obj2);


            System.out.println("¿Son iguales? " + obj1.equals(obj2));

            Iterator iter = Lista.iterator();
            while (iter.hasNext())
              System.out.println(iter.next());


    }

}


public class COSTOS  {
        private int referencia;
        private double monto;
        private String descripcion;
        private String NumeroParte;


        public COSTOS(int referencia, double monto, String descripcion, String numeroParte) {
         this.referencia = referencia;
         this.monto = monto;
         this.descripcion = descripcion;
         this.NumeroParte = numeroParte;
        }

//getters and  setters
```

Este es mi código clase, qué podria estas haciendo o mal o que me falta por implementar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cuando usas

```
System.out.println(loquesea);
```

Lo que hace ese método es (conceptualmente):

```
if (loquesea instanceof String) {
    print(loquesea + "\n");
} else {
    print(loquesea.toString() + "\n");
}
```

Todos los objetos, por extender la clase `Object`, tienen el método toString() ya implementado, pero a menos que lo sobreescribas sólo mostrará el nombre de la clase y código asociado a la dirección de memoria donde se haya (una especie de identificador).

Por tanto la solución es tan simple como hacer que tu clase COSTOS implemente ese método, mostrando lo que tú quieras que se muestre, por ejemplo:

```
public class COSTOS  {
    private int referencia;
    private double monto;
    private String descripcion;
    private String NumeroParte;




    public String toString() {
        return this.referencia + " - " + this.monto + " (" + this.descripcion +")";
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! funciono!

Answer (score -6):

Tiene que poner Arraylist lista=new Arraylist();

No puedes iniciar List Lista=new Arraylist,esto no tiene sentido.

Si usas List estas llamando a la clase List o si usas ArrayList estas llamando a la clase ArrayList,pero lo que tu has puesto no tiene sentido.

A parte,en el iterator deber decirle que quieres que saque,por ejemplo,en el system que te saque el monto,usarías it.getMonto() y te devolvería el monto de cada objeto del iterador,ese system así solo te va a sacar esa información que te aparece,has de usar los getters que has creado para sacar datos.

Comment: ArrayList es una clase que implementa la interfaz List